# Can I make a SonarQube analysis complementary to the previous one instead of overwriting it?

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops

We're using SonarQube in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), which lets you use start-end analysis tasks as well as a SonarQube CLI scanner task. [Like so](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS).

However, if I use both task-types in the same build, aimed at the same project, the results of the last task overwrite the results from the first one. Since we're doing C#/TestCoverage-analysis in one task, and TypeScript-analysis in the other, the results should complement eachother.

Instead, we end up with 2 analysis' uploaded to SonarQube and the project history page flip-flops between *"You started using Typescript-analysis"* and *"You stopped using C#-analysis"*.

I found out there's a parameter called sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports that (supposedly) fixed this, but it is now deprecated? Am I missing something?

Comment: similar issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/2szuYHtxFjU/kYsJYxurBQAJ

Comment: The problem seems to be with VSTS start/end tasks only analyzing .csproj projects. But since our project uses Angular CLI it doesn't have a .csproj and automatically gets left out. If I add a SonarQube CLI-task I can analyse the project as a typescript-project, but I can't use the same Project Key or the previous results get overwritten.

The solution (for now) seems to be to use different keys for BackEnd and FrontEnd-analysis in SQ.